# tikz plots alignment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to produce a figure using

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\makebox[\columnwidth]{\input{try1.tikz}}
\makebox[\columnwidth]{\input{try2.tikz}}
\end{figure}
```

The files `try1.tikz` and `try2.tikz` are given below. The only difference between them is that in the former xmin=-2, in the latter xmin=-4.

I get

[image]

How do I align the panels vertically?

`try1.tikz` is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize\sffamily]

\begin{axis}[%
view={0}{90},
width=4cm,
height=4cm,
scale only axis,
xmin=-2, xmax=1,
ymin=0, ymax=1.7,
name=plot2,
unbounded coords=jump]
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
view={0}{90},
width=4cm,
height=4cm,
scale only axis,
xmin=-2, xmax=1,
ymin=0, ymax=1.7,
at=(plot2.left of south west), anchor=right of south east,
unbounded coords=jump]
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
view={0}{90},
width=4cm,
height=4cm,
scale only axis,
xmin=-2, xmax=1,
ymin=0, ymax=1.7,
at=(plot2.right of south east), anchor=left of south west,
legend style={nodes=right,font=\tiny},
legend pos= north west,
unbounded coords=jump]

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and `try2.tikz` is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize\sffamily]

\begin{axis}[
view={0}{90},
width=4cm,
height=4cm,
scale only axis,
xmin=-4, xmax=1,
ymin=0, ymax=1.7,
name=plot2,
unbounded coords=jump]
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
view={0}{90},
width=4cm,
height=4cm,
scale only axis,
xmin=-4, xmax=1,
ymin=0, ymax=1.7,
at=(plot2.left of south west), anchor=right of south east,
unbounded coords=jump]
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
view={0}{90},
width=4cm,
height=4cm,
scale only axis,
xmin=-4, xmax=1,
ymin=0, ymax=1.7,
at=(plot2.right of south east), anchor=left of south west,
legend style={nodes=right,font=\tiny},
legend pos= north west,
unbounded coords=jump]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This brings immediate attention to the `groupplots` library of [`pgfplots`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots).

Your plot can be realized through:

```
% \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[group style={rows=2,columns=3},
    view={0}{90},
    width=4cm,height=4cm,
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-2, xmax=1,
    bottom plots/.style={xmin=-4},
    ymin=0, ymax=1.7,unbounded coords=jump]
    \nextgroupplot
    \nextgroupplot
    \nextgroupplot
    \nextgroupplot[bottom plots]
    \nextgroupplot[bottom plots]
    \nextgroupplot[bottom plots]
  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which will yield the following image:
[image]

The `groupplot` environment does the following:

1. Determines the number of plots by `rows` and `columns` in the style `group style`. (one can also use `group size=<cols> by <rows>`)
2. Grab each `\nextgroupplot` and places it in column-wise order
3. Each `\nextgroupplot` is equivalent to `\begin{axis} ... \end{axis}`
4. Every option specified in the `groupplot` (and not in the `group style` style) environment will be added
   to each `\nextgroupplot` macro, thereby each `axis` environment.

If you need to adjust the spacing between the plots you have the following styles (which should be placed inside the `group style` key:

- `horizontal sep=<dim>`
- `vertical sep=<dim>`

Thus you can do:

```
 group style={vertical sep=0cm}
```

to make them touch each other in the vertical direction. The `pgfplots` manual has a whole section of this which I highly suggest you read (it is placed under **Related Libraries**).

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `groupplots` library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary[pgfplots.groupplots]

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize\sffamily]
      \begin{groupplot}[
          group style={group size=3 by 2},
          view={0}{90},
          width=4cm,
          height=4cm,
          scale only axis,
          xmin=-2, xmax=1,
          ymin=0, ymax=1.7,
          name=plot2,
          unbounded coords=jump]
        ]
        \nextgroupplot          \addplot [domain=-2:1, thick, cyan] {rnd};
        \nextgroupplot          \addplot [domain=-2:1, thick, cyan] {rnd};
        \nextgroupplot          \addplot [domain=-2:1, thick, cyan] {rnd};
        \nextgroupplot[xmin=-4] \addplot [domain=-4:1, thick, cyan] {rnd};
        \nextgroupplot[xmin=-4] \addplot [domain=-4:1, thick, cyan] {rnd};
        \nextgroupplot[xmin=-4] \addplot [domain=-4:1, thick, cyan] {rnd};
      \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Which produces

[image]

Any option that is common for all plots can go as the optional arguments to the `\begin{groupplot}` command, and any that are specific to each plot can be passed to the `\nextgroupplot` command.

To make the difference between the top and the bottom plots, the best way would probably be by defining a style for all of them, as in zeroth's answer. So I modified my answer to show how options can be passed individually to each `\nextgroupplot`.